# Parse json in PHP sent from javascript

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse the following `json` in `php`:

```
[{"id":"firstname","optionValue":""},{"id":"lastname","optionValue":""},{"id":"","optionValue":"Submit"}]
```

Im getting the string sent to me with a `get request`

This is what i got so far:

```
if(isset($_GET['data'])) {

    $json_a = json_decode($_GET['data'], true);

    foreach ($json_a as $a => $b) {
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

However `echo $a;` does not output anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you sending it? Did you inspect the request? Did you make sure the `if` statement is entered? Are errors on?

Comment: The way you have it there right now, you should be seeing the indexes outputted. $b should contain the "lastname" and "optionValue" data.

Comment: I want to get firstname -> value lastname -> value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have the JSON string decoded properly by doing a `var_dump($json_a);`. If the JSON is not valid, `json_decode()` will return `NULL` and you won't be able to get the contents.

If you can verify that  `json_decode()` is returning an array containing the required information, keep reading.

You have the following in your code:

```
foreach ($json_a as $a => $b) {
    echo $a;
}
```

This will just print out the keys: `0, 1, 2`. You want the value instead. For that, your loop needs to look like below:

```
foreach ($json_a as $value) {
    echo $value['id'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will now print out:

```
firstname
lastname
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/62683)